# Bash pipes and Shell expansions

Tags: bash, shell

I've changed my data source in a bash pipe from `cat ${file}` to `cat file_${part_number}` because preprocessing was causing `${file}` to be truncated at 2GB, splitting the output eliminated the preprocessing issues. However while testing this change, I was unable to work out how to get Bash to continue acting the same for some basic operations I was using to test the pipeline.

My original pipeline is:

```
cat giantfile.json | jq -c '.' | python postprocessor.py
```

With the original pipeline, if I'm testing changes to `postprocessor.py` or the preprocessor and I want to just test my changes with a couple of items from `giantfile.json` I can just use `head` and `tail`. Like so:

```
cat giantfile.json | head -n 2 - | jq -c '.' | python postprocessor.py
cat giantfile.json | tail -n 3 - | jq -c '.' | python postprocessor.py
```

The new pipeline that fixes the issues the preprocessor is:

```
cat file_*.json | jq -c '.' | python postprocessor.py
```

This works fine, since every file gets output eventually. However I don't want to wait 5-10 minutes for each tests. I tried to test with the first 2 lines of input with head.

```
cat file_*.json | head -n 2 - | jq -c '.' | python postprocessor.py
```

Bash sits there working far longer than it should, so I try:

```
cat file_*.json | head -n 2 - | jq -c '.'
```

And my problem is clear. Bash is outputting the content of all the files as if head was not even there because each file now has 1 line of data in it. I've never needed to do this with bash before and I'm flummoxed.

***Why*** does Bash behave this way, and ***How*** do I rewrite my little bash command pipeline to work the way it used to, allowing me to select the first/last *n* lines of data to work with for testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that when you split the json up into individual files, you managed to remove the newline character from the end of each line, with the consequence that the concatenated file (`cat file_json.*`) is really only one line in total, because `cat` will not insert newlines between the files it is concatenating.

If the files were really one line each with a terminating newline character, piping through `head -n 2` should work fine.

You can check this hypothesis with `wc`, since that utility counts newline characters rather than lines. If it reports that the files have 0 lines, then you need to fix your preprocessing.

Comment: You nailed it. Turns out I had a step in the preprocessing that stripped the beeline from the end of the file it worked on. This wasn't an issue with only one file. But causes my issue when it's one line of data per file.